# java asymmetry in right and left shift operators

Tags: java, bit-shift

Consider the following code.

1. 1 >> 34 = 0,
2. 1 << 34 = 4 // circular shift

why such asymmetry ?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? "Why is one shift circular and the other not?" is a fair question.

Comment: Are you assuming that `>>` by value greater than `31` will always give you 0? Try it with `4 >> 34`

Comment: @RohitJain: If you are implying that neither shift is circular, but both are "mod 32" then you should post this as an answer.

Comment: You are making an incorrect assumption and asking why it is so. It is not so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift only uses the lower 5 bits for an int and the lower 6 bit for a long.

> 1 >> 34 = 0

This is the same as 1 >> 2 which is 0 as this is not circular rotation.

> 1 << 34 = 4 // circular shift

This is the same as 1 << 2 as the shift only uses the lower 5 bits for an int and the lower 6 bit for a long.

This is not circular shifting.

e.g.

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE << 1 // is 0
```

Answer (score 5):

From [JLS §15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the **five lowest-order bits** of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value **0x1f (0b11111)**. The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

So, it's not that `<<` is circular and `>>` is not. It's just the value you chose, that made you believe that.

With shifting `1` by `34`, considering the lowest 5 bits:

```
1 >> 34  === 1 >> 2 === 0
1 << 34  === 1 << 2 === 4
```

Since `34 & 0x1F == 2`.

Now, take some larger value, for which bit shifting by `2` will not get you `0` technically:

```
4 >> 34 == 4 >> 2 == 1
4 << 34 == 4 << 34 == 16
```

The shift distance for `int` type are always calculated taking the 5 lowest-order bits. It's not a circular shift operation. Neither of them are. This is how they are intended to behave.

Answer (score 0):

When shifting right with the signed shift operator `1>>34`, following the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), the left is filled up with the sign, in this case, as 1 is positive, the sign is 0. The one gets lost with the first shift `1>>1 = 0`

When shifting left with the signed shift operator `1<<34` the following happens:

```
0x0001<<34 = (0x0001 << 32) << 2 = 0x0004 = 4
```